# Spring 4: failing to config Servlet's mapping

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm struggling with the servlet's configuration of my `Spring MVC web-app`.

- I'am using Intellij IDEA IDE;
- Introduced `spring-boot-starter-parent`, version 1.1.8.RELEASE, as parent in Maven's pom.xml, `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-webmvc` as dependencies;
- Defined a Config class with these beans:

`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"sblog", "sblog.controller", "sblog.repository", "sblog.service"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("sblog.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config {
    ...
    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new DispatcherServlet(); 
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
                dispatcherServlet(), "/*", "/index");
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        System.err.println(registration.getServletName());
        System.err.println(registration.getUrlMappings());
        return registration;
    }
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/resources/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
```

- Defined a class Application:

`

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Config.class, args);
    }
}
```

`
 - Added a simple controller:

`

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        System.err.println("Index");
        return "index";
    }
```

- And defined the following project structure:

`

```
sblog/
├── pom.xml
├── sblog.iml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── sblog
│   │           ├── Application.java
│   │           ├── Config.java
│   │           ├── controller
│   │           │   ├── ApplicationController.java
│   │           │   ├── PageController.java
│   │           │   ├── PostController.java
│   │           │   └── SessionController.java
│   │           ├── orm
│   │           │   ├── Author.java
│   │           │   └── Post.java
│   │           ├── repository
│   │           │   ├── AuthorRepository.java
│   │           │   └── PostRepository.java
│   │           ├── service
│   │           │   └── PostService.java
│   │           └── WebMVCApplicationInitializer.java
│   └── resources
│       └── index.jsp
```

`

But each time I visit the root I get `o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resources/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServletRegistration'`

Thank you in advance, any help will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I suggest a read on what Spring Boot can do for you, you are trying very hard not to use Spring boot.

I suggest dropping all the annotations apart from `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`. Everything else will be added/provided by Spring Boot. I also suggest merging your `Config` and `Application` class into one. Leaving you with the following (yes without the `@Bean` methods)..

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Config.class, args);
    }
}
```

You only need to add `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as dependencies, the other necessary dependencies (`spring-webmvc` etc.) will be added automatically. Of course you still need to add hibernate as a dependency.

Spring Boot will detect Spring Web and configure the `DispatcherServlet` and other beans for you.

Next the `src/resources` directory isn't known so it will not be available as a resource and as such will not be found. I would also suggest NOT using JSP as a view layer. There are some issues with JSP and Spring Boot as explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations). If you really must don't explicitly configure the `InternalResourceViewResolver` but add an `application.properties` file to `src/main/resources` and add the following to properties.

```
spring.view.prefix=
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Which correspond to a the prefix and suffix properties of the `InternalResourceViewResolver`. For a list of properties check [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

I suggest not using the `src/main/resources/resources` folder for storing the JSP pages, as that directory is also publicly readable (by default in Spring Boot). I suggest a `views` directory for instance. Which would lead to the following properties

```
spring.view.prefix=/views/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

A final note Spring Boot powered applications don't detect `WebApplicationInitializer` so if you are doing something inside it it will not be done for Spring Boot applications (unless it is the specific Spring Boot `WebApplicationInitializer`).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the issues with boot and JSP so I switched to thymeleaf, using a starter project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I used the same structure except my 'resources' folder was inside the 'main' folder. Secondly, I used a configuration like following.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class CoreConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter initAdapter(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

If you want further details, please check my example project on [GitHub](https://github.com/furkan3ayraktar/SpringBoot-AngularJS-Bootstrap).